# number of downloads

Tags: applications, google-play-store

How can we find that how many times a specific app has been downloaded? For example, in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vajehyab.app) page I cannot see any information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down and you will find it inside "Installs" under "Additional Information" section. It will show you the range of number of downloads.

Right now, that app shows a range of "10-50" installs.